# How do I require parameters when running tests from setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-unittest, setup.py

I have a Python library which sends requests to an external server that requires a username and password.  In order to run functional tests, I have a [`setUpClass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) method which loads the necessary username and password from pre-defined environmental variables.

```
import os
import unittest

class TestApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpClass(self):
        username = os.environ["username"]
        password = os.environ["password"]
        ...

    def test_misc(self):
        ...
```

Unfortunately, this results in `KeyError: 'password'` when running the test suite from `setup.py`, as the environment variables haven't been set. I want to modify `setup.py` to require values for `username` and `password` before running tests.

```
setup(
    name='MyApp',
    description='AppDescription',
    test_suite='tests',
    # test_requires_values=['username', 'password']
)
```

**How can I require values for `username` and `password` when running tests from `setup.py`?**

Comment: What do you mean by "require"? Should some default values for both env vars be set in the setup script to ensure they are available in tests? Or should the `setup()` function fail early when the env vars are not found? If the env vars are missing, the test will fail on setup anyway, isn't this enough?

Comment: @hoefling I wasn’t sure if there was a standard way of handling required parameters in setup.py.